# mysql restore file.sql syntax error using command line

Tags: mysql, database-restore

when I input

```
mysql -u root -p XXXX dbname < c:/filename.sql
```

alway get this error "error 1064 <42000>:" you have an error in your SQL suntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySql server version for the right syntax to use near .....

what is wrong with this statement?

Comment: there's nothing wrong with the statement, its the filename.sql, most probably something to do with your query check out the error

Comment: when i put mysqldump -u username -ppassword database_name > dump.sql; I get same error 1064 <42000>:...

Answer (score 1):

I resolved it using PowerShell:

> Get-Content "c:/filename.sql" | .\mysql.exe -uroot -pXXXX dbname

Answer (score 0):

It is due to a reserved word in MySQL, typically because of a version mismatch.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/reserved-words.html

Answer (score 0):

right one is 
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\bin>mysqldump -u root -p mysql>backup_database.sql
    Enter password: ********

my path not right. Should not log into mysql and then execute that statement